# UPDATE LIMIT statement in PHP causes syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, limit

```
$query1 = "update rooms set available='1' where typeId='$typeId' order by roomId limit='$room'";
```

I am getting syntax error near near '='1'' but I can't find the error. I'm pretty sure it's written correctly.

Comment: For this question and its answers, readers should be aware of the possibility of SQL injection here. Ordinary `WHERE` statements should use parameter binding, and the injected value in the `LIMIT` should be cast to an integer before usage.

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT can't assign values, remove the quotes. Change it to:

```
$query1 = "update rooms set available='1' where typeId='$typeId' order by roomId limit $room";
```

Comment: Thanks i removed the = sign but now it says error near "1" .

Comment: @Ailynn I have answered try that

Comment: @Ailynn Sorry, I forgot to remove those quotations. Remove those. try the updated one

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, `LIMIT` can not be assigned and you can't use quotes around the limit number, so use this:

```
 $query1 = "update rooms set available = '1' where typeId = '$typeId' order by roomId limit $room ";
```

Don't use `'$room'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query to this:

```
$query1 = "update `rooms` set available='1' where typeId='$typeId' order by roomId limit '$room'";
```